# What is the best way to mark a deleted Node?

Tags: neo4j

I want to mark node as deleted (and not actually delete the node) and i'm not sure if to set a property in the node(deleted:0/1) or set label to the deleted node. which way is more efficient and right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my point of view it's label, because they are indexed by default.

This article could help you - http://graphaware.com/neo4j/2015/01/16/neo4j-graph-model-design-labels-versus-indexed-properties.html

Answer (score 1):

It depends entirely on your use case. In many cases you will actually delete the node. For others you can set a property or add a label. From a performance point of view there shouldn't be much of a difference.

The most important thing is to understand how your application is going to interact with the node that is marked deleted. Do you still want it searchable? How are people searching now and if you don't want it searchable what is the easiest way for you to modify your query to exclude deleted information? Will you ever need to restore the node or query it at a later time?